# R - Running Score Column For Sports Results

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataset of goals scored in football matches, ordered by the match and the sequence in which the goals were scored. It is in the following format. At present I only have the first 2 columns, the 3rd is what I am struggling to produce:

```
Goal.Sequence     Goal.Difference     Running.Difference
0                 0                   0
1                 1                   1
2                -1                   0
25                0                   0
0                 0                   0
1                 1                   1
2                 1                   2
3                -1                   1
4                 1                   2
25                0                   2
0                 0                   0
1                -1                  -1
2                -1                  -2
25                0                  -2
```

Each row represents a goal scored except for any row with sequence number 0 or 25 (these are dummy rows for match start point and match end point). The Goal.Difference column represents the goal from the home teams point of view (+1 if they scored, -1 if they conceded). The sample of my data above therefore represents 3 different matches whose results were 1-1, 3-1 and 0-2.

I want to create the third column for the running score differential in the match but which restarts at every new match. I am struggling to do this and any help would be appreciated.

Follows some example data:

```
# Provide data in a usable format (e.g. using dput on your data object)
scores <- structure(list(Goal.Sequence = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 25L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
                                           3L, 4L, 25L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 25L),
                         Goal.Difference = c(0L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,
                                             -1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, -1L, 0L)),
                    .Names = c("Goal.Sequence", "Goal.Difference", "match"),
                    row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a label that indicates which match a row is part of:

```
labl <- cumsum(df$Goal.Sequence==25)
```

then you can do a match-based cumsum via

```
ave(df$Goal.Difference, labl, FUN=cumsum)
```

Comment: Thanks but when I run this I receive the following message: Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors
Any ideas what I am doing wrong here please?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to name the third argument to `ave` - have corrected now

Comment: Also, just noticed in your data that you've now provided that we should probably define labels by changing `==25` to `==0` if you want to reset the scores at each 0 rather than at each 25.

Comment: I like how the use of `ave` simplifies the calculation. Regardless, you should consider fixing the structure of your data to have one column per variable and avoid using dummy rows. Most statistical functions and plotting will work better that way.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to keep each variable to its own column. Given that, there are many ways of doing what you need. For example:

```
# Keep track of each match in its own variable. Use filter from package stats
scores$match <- as.integer(stats::filter(x=scores$Goal.Sequence==0,
                 filter=1, method='recursive'))

# Drop the dummy rows
scores <- scores[!scores$Goal.Sequence %in% c(0,25),]

# Run a cumsum on the Goal.Difference by match
library(package=dplyr)  # Very useful for data manipulation

scores <- scores %.%
 group_by(match) %.%
 mutate(Running.Difference=cumsum(Goal.Difference)) %.%
 select(match, Goal.Sequence, Goal.Difference, Running.Difference)
```